# Is this a long-standing bug that's never been fixed in Undo class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, undo, undo-redo

Take the following code:

```
var go = new GameObject("test");

Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(go, "Object created!");

Undo.AddComponent(go, typeof(BoxCollider));
```

When you open the menu for undoing, you will see:

> Undo Object created!

When you open the menu for redoing, you will see:

> Redo AddComponent

In other terms, the `AddComponent` always overrides the action name you've set originally.

No matter which [of the functions in `Undo` class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.html) you try such as the following:

```
FlushUndoRecordObjects
IncrementCurrentGroup
RecordObject    
RegisterCompleteObjectUndo  
RegisterCreatedObjectUndo   
RegisterFullObjectHierarchyUndo 
SetCurrentGroupName
```

It is impossible to get a consistent undo/redo pair to show in the menu...

Any ideas?

Unity 2020.3.11f1 LTS

Comment: I don't think it's a bug .. did you confirm the object actually has the component attached? I think you still have to actually call `go.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();` since the `Undo.AddComponent` is only taking track of the undo redo .. it afaik doesn't actually perform that action. So I guess it is in the `Redo` panel since it thinks the action was undone .. because it was never actually done .. but that's just a wild guess ;)

Comment: No, Undo.AddComponent indeed adds the component. It's just that no matter what you try, such as even adding some changes to the object and record them after `AddComponent`, the redo in menu will always show `Redo AddComponent`.